# Mule gives error when making http request from JBoss

Tags: mule, jboss7.x

I have a Mule flow which is trying to make outboud HTTP request.

```
    <http:request config-ref="APP_OUT" path="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.path']" method="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.method']" doc:name="OUT"  sendBodyMode="ALWAYS" parseResponse="false"  followRedirects="false">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="HOST" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'host']"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

This works from Mule studio as well as when running Mule as a standalone Java application. However, when I take this to JBoss7 as webapp, I get error immediately. We can rule out the Timeout errors which I get after few seconds.

```
16:56:27,393 SEVERE [org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner] ([myapp].http.requester.APP_OUT(1) SelectorRunner) doSelect exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.HttpTransactionContext.getAsyncHandler()Lcom/ning/http/client/AsyncHandler; from class org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.getWorkManager(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:119) [mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.getThreadPoolFor(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:90) [mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(FlowWorkManagerIOStrategy.java:69) [mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar:3.7.2]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:414) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:383) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:347) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:278) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571) [grizzly-framework-2.3.21.jar:2.3.21]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

Does anyone know if this is a known issue? I can see someone else has posted same question on MuleSoft forum with no response

http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/30322/mule-372-issue-when-using-httprequest-and-running-1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are conflicting versions of `async-http-client` on the classpath, or more precisely that the version of `com.ning.http.client.providers.grizzly.HttpTransactionContext` that has been class-loaded is not version expected by Mule's HTTP Module (which has thus been compiled with a different version).

Mule `3.7` expects `1.9.21`: do you have a different version packaged in your Mule application? Or does JBoss load in a parent classloader a different version? If the former, review your app's POM to make sure the proper version gets packaged, if the latter, configure JBoss classloader to avoid providing an incompatible version of this class to your Mule application.

**EDIT**: Thanks to the OP's comment, the problem is indeed due to the fact the Mule HTTP Module embeds a different version of `HttpTransactionContext`. One of the difference is about making `getAsyncHandler` public so it can be called from anywhere (see [original](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/async-http-client-1.9.27/src/main/java/com/ning/http/client/providers/grizzly/HttpTransactionContext.java#L158) and [Mule's fork](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.7.2/modules/http/src/main/java/com/ning/http/client/providers/grizzly/HttpTransactionContext.java#L154)).

This works in Mule Standalone because of [the way Mule loads classes with its system classloader](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/classloader-control-in-mule): precedence is given to JARs in `lib/mule` over `lib/opt`. The HTTP Module JAR is in the former while `async-http-client` is in the latter. Thus the expected version of `HttpTransactionContext` gets loaded.

This is really unfortunate as it makes running Mule applications outside of Mule Standalone very difficult, if not impossible.

In your case, check what JBoss' classloader allows you to do: maybe it can allow you to fine tune it and give precedence to the Mule JARs above the other JARs. Alternatively, you'd need to build a fork of `async-http-client` where the Mule version of `HttpTransactionContext` would be used instead. You could also bring the Mule version of this class in your own project, which should take precedence over the versions in JARs.

Comment: JBoss7 do not contain the `HttpTransactionContext` class. My project however has this in two locations 1) async-http-client-1.9.27.jar and 2) mule-module-http-3.7.2.jar. Both the classes are in the exact same package. If I try to exclude the async-http-client from my project then I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ning.http.client.AsyncHandler` exception. I dont understand why Mule JAR contains class from other public library and at the same time have Maven dependency on the same library.

Comment: @user1431708 I've edited my answer accordingly. I suggest you report this as a bug https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE and share the JIRA ID here so we can upvote/keep track of it.

Comment: In made a local fix by copying the source code for the HttpTransactionContext.java from mule-module-http to my src/main/java which takes precedence over the content of the WEB-INF/lib directory.

The issue has been reported to Mulesoft [Mule-89989](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8989)

Comment: It begs the question "who at Mulesoft thought this was a good idea"? Clearly someone that hated developers.

Comment: In case anyone runs into this problem on Heroku, I was able to resolve it by forcing the load of mule-module-http-{version}.jar first in the procfile like this:

web:    java -cp target/dependency/mule-module-http-3.8.0.jar:target/dependency/*:target/classes:target/lib/* {Launcher Class} {Port}

Comment: I know it is issue from 2016, but I have same problem with CE 3.8.1 and I can not resolve it :c