# Mule: NoClassDefFoundError during after successful flow processing

Tags: mule

I have the following flow setup:

```
    <set-variable variableName="year" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.year]" doc:name="setYear"/>     
    <set-variable variableName="month" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.month]" doc:name="setMonth"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/year/{year}/month/{month}/file.csv" method="GET" doc:name="deliverFile">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:uri-param paramName="year" value="#[flowVars.year]"/>
                <http:uri-param paramName="month" value="#[flowVars.month]"/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
         <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="The request cannot be processed, the error is #[exception.getSummaryMessage()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </catch-exception-strategy>
```

Everything works fine & I am able to download the file however, at the end I get the following error:

SEVERE: doSelect exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.grizzly.localization.LogMessages
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.executeIoEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeyEvents(SelectorRunner.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.iterateKeys(SelectorRunner.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doSelect exception may be the bug already reported here https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MULE-8989
This may have fixed in mule runtime 3.8.2 : https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-3.8.2-release-notes
Just try with the latest mule runtime
For more ref: [Mule gives error when making http request from JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957946/mule-gives-error-when-making-http-request-from-jboss)

Comment: Hello Anirban, Thanks for the Tip..however I am on Mule runtime 3.8.3, so this bug should'nt have happened in first place if fixed in previous versions